# What is the alternative to `Collection<T>`, for Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

Given [`List<T>` is considered bad as a base class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/faq-why-does-donotexposegenericlists-recommend-that-i-expose-collection-lt-t-gt-instead-of-list-lt-t-gt-david-kean.aspx), and `Collection<T>` doesn't appear to be available in the subset of the framework available to <s>Metro</s> Windows Store applications, what base class should be used in place of `Collection<T>` to allow for extensibility, such as raising an event when an item is added or removed from the it?

Comment: Why do you think `Collection<T>` is not available? It is supported by the Portable Class Library.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth because Intelisense isn't showing it as an option for me?

Comment: Have you added `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`?

Comment: I'd have changed both the classes in that article to expose `ICollection<T>` (or even `IEnumerable<T>` if it sufficed), rather than any concrete class, without a clear reason for exposing concrete.

Comment: OK, my bad, was just importing the wrong namespace :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface.

Comment: In my case, I'm reimplementing `Table<T>` and parts of `DataContext` (as Linq to SQL isn't available), and I'm trying to maintain a certain amount of familiarity. Normally, I would expose an interface.

Comment: Exposing an interface would mean having to cast on the consumption (a lot), and would lead to inconsistencies on differing platforms, which is "less than ideal". I appreciate your point, and I'm normally the first to highlight when a method is returning a concrete type instead of a suitable interface...